# JS class getter setters

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

According to [Martin](https://m.dotdev.co/how-to-use-classes-in-node-js-with-no-pre-compilers-and-why-you-should-ad9ffd63817d), this syntax can be used to define a class in nodeJS:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.id = 'id_1';
  }
  set name(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
}
```

usage:

```
myPerson.name = "Saul"; // save the value in `_name` variable.
```

Slight problem with this convention is that calling `JSON.stringify(myPerson)` will print the following:

```
{
  "_name": "Saul"
}
```

But if I remove the underline from the setter function, and write it as the following:

```
  set name(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
```

the setter function will recursively call itself forever. So is there no way of using this nice getter-setter syntax, and still use the `name` property? I'm running nodejs.

Comment: Dont. Dont use getters / setters at all here.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a problem at all here. If you deserialize it, it works as expected:

```
 const saul = Object.assign(new Person, JSON.parse('{"_name": "Saul"}'));
 console.log(saul.name);
```

Comment: The problem is that JS here (and any big system I imagine) is only part of the system. And all parts need to deliver the agreed properties. Or is underlining beginning of properties a cross-language treat?

Comment: @makan good point. But then the dupe provides a good solution for this